# How do you call a class and its method when its stored in a pointer array

Tags: c++, pointers, methods, call

How do you use a pointer and call the class methods it points to?

For example:

```
Image *img[26];

Image IM = outputImage();
img[0] = &IM;
```

I want to call img[0], or IM's methods.  I tried something like this but I received errors.

```
img[0].getPixel(0,1);
```

The error is "expression must have a class type"

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a pointer array, you must dereference it as a pointer.

```
 img[0]->getPixel(0, 1);
```

And this:

```
 Image IM = outputImage();
```

should be:

```
 Image &IM = outputImage();
```

Assuming that `outputImage()` returns a reference.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following two methods:
1) use -> operator to the member function.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class myclass
{
    public:
        void printHello()
        {
            cout<<"hello from  class"<<endl;
        }
};
int main()
{
    myclass *s[10];
    myclass inst;
    s[0]=&inst;
    s[0]->printHello();
    return 0;
}
```

2) use . after de-referencing the pointer.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class myclass
{
    public:
        void printHello()
        {
            cout<<"hello from  class"<<endl;
        }
};
int main()
{
    myclass *s[10];
    myclass inst;
    s[0]=&inst;
    (*s[0]).printHello();
    return 0;
}
```